# User Interface Changes for Mac when Porting Windows Application

Tags: gui-design, windows-os, mac-os-x

I have an existing windows application, for which I have decided to create a Mac version. The problem is that the current UI involves a lot of buttons, tabbed panels, multiple windows etc.

This UI had been rated as intuitive and easy to use and straightforward by many customers and editors. But a beginner (very less experience) may find in confusing a little, but it has been complemented with tutorial.

When creating the Macintosh variant, should I focus on creating a simplified and minimalistic UI (this does not mean the current UI is complex, but I think Mac user's prefer a simple UI right?) or should I try to copy the exact same thing?

By reducing the UI some of the features may be missing. But it can be added later if needed. Should I focus on a fresh approach (this is easier rather than copying the complex UI pattern) or should I go with the old recognized setup?